# faultCode=NO_PREFIX_SPECIFIED: Unable to determine namespace of '

Tags: wcf, soapui, wcf-binding, mtom

I have a WSDL . Following  WSDL i am trying to  try in SoapUI

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="NextGenService" targetNamespace="">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="DocumentExchangePort_policy">...</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message">
<xs:simpleType name="StreamBody">
<xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary"/>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SupportingDocsFacade"/>
<xs:element name="RemoteFileInfo">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" name="FileByteStream" type="q1:StreamBody"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SupportingDocsFacade" name="dcExhange" nillable="true" type="q2:DocumentExchangeRequests"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SupportingDocsFacade" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SupportingDocsFacade">
<xs:complexType name="DocumentExchangeRequests">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="_documentDescription" nillable="true" type="tns:DescriptionSet"/>
<xs:element name="_loanIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns:LoanFileIdentifier"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="DocumentExchangeRequests" nillable="true" type="tns:DocumentExchangeRequests"/>
<xs:complexType name="DescriptionSet">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="_documentType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_ByteCount_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_DocumentCreated_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_DocumentDescrption_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_DocumentID_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_PageCount_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="DescriptionSet" nillable="true" type="tns:DescriptionSet"/>
<xs:complexType name="LoanFileIdentifier">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="_x003C_ApplyOnlineID_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_BrokerID_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="_x003C_DocumentID_x003E_k__BackingField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="LoanFileIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns:LoanFileIdentifier"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="RemoteFileInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo_Headers">
<wsdl:part name="dcExhange" element="dcExhange"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="INextGenService_UploadDocNextGen_OutputMessage"/>
<wsdl:portType name="INextGenService">
<wsdl:operation name="UploadDocNextGen">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:INextGenService/UploadDocNextGen" name="RemoteFileInfo" message="RemoteFileInfo"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:INextGenService/UploadDocNextGenResponse" message="INextGenService_UploadDocNextGen_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="DocumentExchangePort" type="INextGenService">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#DocumentExchangePort_policy"/>
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="UploadDocNextGen">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:INextGenService/UploadDocNextGen" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="RemoteFileInfo">
<soap12:header message="RemoteFileInfo_Headers" part="dcExhange" use="literal"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="NextGenService">
<wsdl:port name="DocumentExchangePort" binding="DocumentExchangePort">
<soap12:address location="https://l24-a0845.latrobe.biz/SupportingDocsFacade/NextGenService.svc/UploadDoc"/>
<wsa10:EndpointReference>
<wsa10:Address>
https://l24-a0845.latrobe.biz/SupportingDocsFacade/NextGenService.svc/UploadDoc
</wsa10:Address>
</wsa10:EndpointReference>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The webconfig in server to generate the following  looks like this

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
         <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  transactionFlow="false" textEncoding="utf-8"  >
        
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="NextGenServiceBehavior" name="SupportingDocsFacade.NextGenService">
        <endpoint address="/UploadDoc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsBinding" name="Basic" contract="SupportingDocsFacade.INextGenService" />

      </service>
    </services>



 <behavior name="NextGenServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          
        </behavior>
```

I wrote a client and is it is able to communicate with the  service .

The issue came when i tried importing WSDL in SOAP UI
[image]

Following is the  RemoteFileInfo class  used for WCF service

```
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
    {

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public DocumentExchangeRequests dcExhange;

        [MessageBodyMember]
        public Stream FileByteStream;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    [MessageContract]

    public class DocumentExchangeRequests
    {
        private DescriptionSet _documentDescription = null;
        private LoanFileIdentifier _loanIdentifier = null;
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public DescriptionSet DocumentDescriptionset
        {
            get { return _documentDescription = this.DocumentDescriptionset; }
            set { this.DocumentDescriptionset = value; }
        }


        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public LoanFileIdentifier LoanIdentifier
        {
            get { return _loanIdentifier = this.LoanIdentifier; }
            set { this.LoanIdentifier = value; }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]

    [MessageContract]
    public class DescriptionSet
    {

        private string _documentType = "";
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string DocumentTypes
        {
            get { return _documentType = this.DocumentTypes; }
            set { this.DocumentTypes = value; }
        }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string DocumentID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string ByteCount { get; set; }


        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string DocumentCreated { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string PageCount { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string DocumentDescrption { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]

    [MessageContract]
    public class LoanFileIdentifier
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0, Name = "DocHeaderID")]
        public string DocumentID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1, Name = "BrokerID")]
        public string BrokerID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2, Name = "ApplyOnlineID")]
        public string ApplyOnlineID { get; set; }
    }
```

Any pointer on what is causing the issue .  I have been cracking head over this for a week .  Is this anything to do with the setting  in soapUI or my WSDL itself is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

WSDL, web service description language, this file doesn’t contain data contract of the service, only XSD files contain the Data Contracts and WSDL has import directives for those XSD files.
Due to this dependency on other files, processing such these WSDL files by some third-party was impossible. Therefore WCF4.5 publish the service metadata by using a Single file. all WSDL information is returned in one single document including some other information.
In SOAPUI, we could use the SingleWSDL file to generate the project.

> http://10.157.13.69:1100/Service1.svc?singleWsdl

[image]
The premise is that we enable metadata publishing via the Http or Https protocol.
Here is a helpful link, wish it is useful to you.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/09/17/whats-new-in-wcf-45-a-single-wsdl-file/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: i used singlewsdl only